# Phase Shift Oscillator Feedback Gain

Tags: filter, oscillator, phase-shift

I'm having trouble getting to the result of the feedback gain (β) of the following phase shift oscillator:

[image: Phase Shift Oscillator]

Is the circuit correctly designed?

How do I calculate the feedback gain?

Edit: Is it possible that the B in the image doesn't correspond to this oscillator?

Comment: The circuit diagram is correct. It is a phaseshift oscillator with 3rd-order highpass in the feedback loop. However, it is not yet designed finally.

Comment: For oscillation, the feedback factor must be real-negative. Because the numerator is imaginary you must set the real part of the denumerator equal to zero. This equation (Re=0) gives you the oscillation frequency.